# Having Trouble Sorting CoreData backed NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

Im trying to retrieve an array of sorted objects from my Core Data backed NSArrayController. Once the ManagedObjectContext is ready I fire a Notification which the object owning the NSArrayController listens for and then sets up the fetch request with sortDescriptors. However the data is NEVER sorted. I've been pounding my head on this for several hours now.

I get the expected data in the array but it's not sorted at all. Anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
// Elsewhere in code
...
_charts = [[NSArrayController alloc] init];
_charts.entityName = @"Charts";
...

// When Cored Data and Managed Object Context is ready
-(void)mangagedObjectContextReady
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = ((AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate]).managedObjectContext;
    _charts.managedObjectContext = moc;
    _charts.usesLazyFetching = NO;
    _charts.automaticallyPreparesContent = YES;
    _charts.automaticallyRearrangesObjects = YES;

    // Create fetch request for data
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Charts" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    // Create the sort descriptors for the Charts entity
    // Name and chartType are properties on the entity "Charts"
    NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSSortDescriptor *chartTypeDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"chartType" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[nameDescriptor, chartTypeDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [_charts fetchWithRequest:fetchRequest merge:NO error:&error];
    if(!success)
        NSLog(@"Error %@:", [error localizedDescription]);
    else {
       [_charts rearrangeObjects];
       [_tv reloadData];
    }
```

I use this method to get an array or sorted objects.. but data is not sorted as per above sort descriptors?

```
[_charts.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:row]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_charts.sortDescriptors = @[nameDescriptor, chartTypeDescriptor];

Comment: Wow that was almost stupidly obvious. I thought putting the sort descriptor on the fetch request was supposed to sort the data as it inserted it into the Arraycontroller. Least that is what all the docs say?

Comment: You do get sorted results from the fetch. Rearranging the array controller probably has its own ideas about sorting.

Comment: I don't. I comment out setting sortDescriptors on the ArrayController as well as all those flags re autoPrepareContent, autoRearrange, and the call to [_charts rearrangedObjects], and use [_charts arrangedObjects] and data is not sorted. Simply seems to ignore the sortDescriptors on the fetchRequest? Might be time to file a bug report.

Comment: [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] should give sorted results. [arrayController fetchWithRequest:fetchRequest merge:NO error:&error] may be substituting its own sort order